# onPause method is not being called

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm new to android development and now I'm trying to understand lifecycle of android activity.

I have these methods to print out the lifecycle process on logcat:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d(tag, "In the onCreate() event");
}

public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(tag, "In the onStart() event");
}

public void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    Log.d(tag, "In the onRestart() event");
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(tag, "In the onResume() event");
}

public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(tag, "In the onStop() event");
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(tag, "In the onDestroy() event");
}
```

Problem is onPause() is never being called. I tried to press home button, select other app from recent app list, turn off the screen display but it just directly call onStop() instead of calling onPause() followed by onStop(). The book I'm reading said that it's supported to be onPause() followed by onStop() if the activity is pushed into background.

Book content:

```
Click the Phone button on the Android emulator so that the activity is pushed to the background. 
Observe the output in the LogCat window:
11-16 06:32:00.585: D/Lifecycle(559): In the onPause() event
11-16 06:32:05.015: D/Lifecycle(559): In the onStop() event
```

I'm testing on real device running 4.2.2 and virtual device running 2.3.3 but the result are the same. Am I just misunderstanding the purpose of onPause or I'm doing wrong to the onPause to be invoked?

**EDIT :** Can you please tell me if onStop() is called after onPause() when will the onResume() be called? Isn't onResume supported to resume which is paused by onPause()? In my test program, onResume() is only called after onStart() not after onPause(). May be because I have only one activity?

Comment: You aren't overriding `Activity.onPause`.

Comment: The code doesn't show any logging for the `onPause()` method. How do you know it isn't being called? Trust me...it WILL be called.

Comment: Thanks everyone who are kind enough to answer my stupid question. I can't believe I didn't notice that. :(

Comment: Happens to everybody :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not override onPause() method.

```
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(tag, "In the onPause() event");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`onPause` is called for sure. But I cannot see an overwritten `onPause` in your code.

`onStop` is called after `onPause` when the system thinks it's a good idea to hibernate the activity. This usually happens when you switch apps etc. `onResume` is called after `onStart` when the activity/fragment is shown. `onResume` is the place where you dump code that shall be run just before the user sees the UI.

Comment: hi @meredrica, can you please answer my EDIT question? :)

Comment: there you go. hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

When overriding a method in Java, it's a very good habit to use the [`@Override`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/94361/693752) annotation :

```
@Override  // <---- THIS !
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(tag, "In the onDestroy() event");
}
```

This way, the compiler will help you in case you misspelled the name of the method, it will say that the method is not an override.

Try to always do it to emphasize that this method is overridden, not a simple method.

And here, yes, others are right, you didn't override `onPause` method. You can't say whether or not it is invoked.